# lb (loopback cli) command not found - MacOS

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal, loopbackjs, loopback

I'm trying to install loopback globally using:

```
npm i -g loopback-cli
```

then when I run the command `lb` I get :

> bash: lb: command not found

when I do nano `~/.bashrc` or nano `~/.bash_profile` I see an empty file.

Then I entered in those files

```
export PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/bin/lb
```

`lb` still **not working**, But then my other commands stopped working (node, ng, etc etc) too. Then I went back and erased those 2 files that I created, and my old commands went back to work, but the lb didn't work.

Comment: That should work. Try updating `npm`maybe? Also, do you use the lastest macOs version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try lb4 for latest version of loopback.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, installed using the command:

```
$ sudo npm install -g @loopback/cli
```

It not worked:

```
$ lb4
-bash: lb4: command not found
```

But it worked by path:

```
$ /usr/local/opt/node/bin/lb4 app
? Project name: (projects)
```

I created an alias in .bash_profile:

```
alias lb4="/usr/local/opt/node/bin/lb4"
```

And now working fine:

```
$ lb4 app
? Project name: (bayma)
```

nvm: **No** 
node version: **v12.14.1** 
macOS: **10.14.6** 
error **-bash: lb4: command not found**

Answer (score 0):

I had success with version 3.

```
sudo -i yarn global add loopback-cli
```